# Java how to remove one line in a file?

Tags: java, file

I want to delete one line of record in a File using Java, example in my file,

```
studentID  studentName studentAddress studentPhoneNo
AAA|AAA AAA | AAAAAAAAAAA | AAAAAAAAAAAA
BBB|BBB BBB | BBBBBBBBBBB | BBBBBBBBBBBB
CCC|CCC CCC | CCCCCCCCCCC | CCCCCCCCCCCC
```

Let said I want to delete studentID= BBB below are the code I found from google :

```
try {

        File inFile = new File(studentFile);

        if (!inFile.isFile()) {
            System.out.println("Parameter is not an existing file");
            return;
        }

        // Construct the new file that will later be renamed to the original
        // filename.
        File tempFile = new File(inFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".tmp");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(studentFile));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

        String line = null;

        // Read from the original file and write to the new
        // unless content matches data to be removed.
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            if (!line.trim().contains(id)) {

                pw.println(line);
                pw.flush();
            }
        }
        pw.close();
        br.close();

        // Delete the original file
        if (!inFile.delete()) {
            System.out.println("Could not delete file");
            return;
        }

        // Rename the new file to the filename the original file had.
        if (!tempFile.renameTo(inFile))
            System.out.println("Could not rename file");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I got this error Could not delete file.

Comment: Just for the case you don't want to use Java: `grep -v BBB yourfile >yournewfile`

Comment: This is exactly what it is: the program cannot delete the file: either because something else is using the file or because the user does not have permissions to delete the file.

Comment: Oh, and you also don't want to just check for string containing `BBB`, because that substring may be part of another column's value.

Comment: I am using Eclipse to run, I had set the file to full control, but I still getting the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

I just tested this program, which runs perfectly fine and produces the expected result (on Windows).
So the problem is not with the code, it's probably a permission problem?

But as said in the comments, if you just assume that your string will be found only as the "Student ID" in your file, that can (and WILL) lead to bugs.

The proper way to do it is to read the content of the file, turn it into a list of Students (class with student id as field, and the other fields as well if you want), remove the one with the student id you don't want, then save the file again with the remaining list serialized to your specific format.

Answer (score 1):

This code doesn't have issues, you do not have permission to delete the file from server. One more thing is, change the logic to find the matching line.

Comment: I am using Eclipse to run, I had set the file to full control, but I still getting the same problem.